# MICKEY 2.0: Mutual irregular clocking, register states

Tags: stream-cipher

I'm trying to understand how MICKEY 2.0 works in detail.

In [1], page 6, it says:

> ... the state of the generator does not repeat within the generation of a single keystream sequence ...

What consequences does this have? As the internal state generates the output, I think that two identical inputs within the same keystream sequence therefore have different outputs. Or are there any other reasons for this?

Further, on page 6 it says:

> The influence of R on the clocking of S also prevents S from
>   becoming stuck in a short cycle

As I read, a short cycle in this context is a sequence of continuously recurring states. Because the state of S depends on the output of R (whose states do not repeat), also the state of S does not repeat within the generation of a single keystream sequence. Is that right?

What exactly is meant by the *mutual irregular clocking*? I think that this refers to the dependence between register R and register S (see Fig. 3, page 6). The output of each of them depends on the state of the other one. As they are not clocking in regular time intervals, the term *irregular clocking* is used.

[1] http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/p3ciphers/mickey/mickey_p3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any keystream generator, if the state repeats, so does the keystream; which, under some standards assumptions, can be detected, and leads to a serious break (e.g. if the beginning of the plaintext is known for length a little above $k+\log_2k$ bits, where $k$ is the period of the keystream, then the period $k$ and the rest of the plaintext can be found). A necessary condition for security is thus that odds of the state repeating are negligibly low. This is insured (odds are zero) if the quoted property holds:

> ... the state of the generator does not repeat within the generation of a single keystream sequence ...

and that's why that property is desirable: it insures there is no class of weak keys leading to attack.

I'm not seeing assertion in the article, or simple proof, that “the state of S does not repeat within the generation of a single keystream sequence”. Rather, I see the reasonable assertion, without formal proof, that starting from a generator S based on iterating a lossless function, and using another *unrelated* generator R as an excitation to S by a combination with XOR keeping the iterated function lossless, it seems unlikely that the resulting generator S' ends up having a period shorter than R (that could occur only for a limited number of R having some sort of tight relation to S; perhaps that's even demonstrable). Rather, it is expected (in the absence of feedback of S to R, and if the function used in S is random enough) that S' has period a large multiple of the period of R, with the large factor commensurate to the square root of the number of possible states for S.